# What would an Electrical Engineer do at a Copper Fab business?

Tags: interview-questions

I am going to interview soon at a Copper Fab business. They found my resume and called me for an interview later this week. He said that there might be some synergy between his business and electrical engineering. (About 80% of the copper components he produces are used in electrical components such as electrical motors.)

In what ways can an Electrical Engineer help at this copper fab company?

Comment: He actually said *synergy*? Beware.

Comment: hahaha yes, he said synergy. Why is that an alert to "beware"?

Comment: It sounds like a market research / strategic planning / business development position.  Reading between the lines, they want to expand their sales to the electrical machinery industry.

Comment: This is a question you should be asking them, not us.  Perhaps the union labor rate is getting so high that it's cheaper to have a electrical engineer drive a truck, clean the smelter, make sure there are towels in the bathroom, etc.

Comment: I said beware because the word 'synergy' is a buzzword that means nothing and gives off quite an air of sleaze, IMHO. Watch out for a situation like Olin mentions. I've been on an interview where it was pretty much how he describes. "Yeah, we're looking for an EE. You'll have to run this waterjet cutting machine for 8 hours a day, but maybe we have a PC or two you could fix in your downtime." Excuse me, what? No thanks.

Comment: @dextorb But think of all the front panels you could cut free of charge for your spare time electronics projects ...

Comment: I think that company may just be looking for a *token* electrical engineer so that they appear more savvy to their sophisticated customers who employ electrical engineers. Hey look, we're not just dumb copper cutters, ya know! Let me transfer you to our electrical engineering department which can talk the electrical talk (over to you now).

Comment: I think this is a good question, but this is the wrong format since it's essentially an opinion poll. Chat would probably be best.

Comment: "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." Like Phil says, this would be a great question for chat at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering .

Answer (score 4):

This is not the job for you.  Walk away.

At best they are thinking of getting into a particular market area or serving it better, so they want someone on staff that can speak EE to customers and advise people in-house on how to do things in a way their EE customers would like.

At worst, they are (from your perspective) knuckle-dragging apes that have heard copper gets used for that 'tricity stuff and they want a wizard to get them to sell more of it to more of those 'tricity folks with the pointy ears but big wallets, so the pointy ears don't matter.  The guys on the factory floor will laugh at your pointy ears as soon as your back is turned, and the boss pretends to not notice because he'd be right there laughing with them if he weren't the boss, but he is, so he has to pretend.  They really have no idea what a electrical engineer does, and can barely spell "EE", so will think you're overpriced at half your normal rate.

The second case is clearly bad for anyone.  The first case isn't for you because you are too young.  There won't be a senior EE around to learn from, which at 25 is very important.  Even if there was, you'd be getting exposed to a dark and obscure corner of EE anyway.  This is simply not appropriate for your career at this time.  Even in the best case scenario, this requires someone with a decent amount of experience, not only knowing some EE and design practises, but more importantly, knowing how to deal with EE customers and how to be right, know you're right, and say "no" to mamagement when the situation calls for it.  A 25 year old should not be put into this position.  At a company with a real engineering department they'd know that, but I expect these people don't.  Run away.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a very fair question the interviewer. I also believe it's best to be honest with yourself and with the interviewer as to what you would be expected to do for them. Questions like:

How will having an electrical engineer on staff benefit his company?

What role does he see you playing?

If they mostly manufacture electrical motor components, and that's where you're expected to lend your expertise, what would your role in the manufacturing process be? Interaction with customers? Design of components? Is this something you want to do on a day to day basis?

Know what you're getting into and what will be expected of you. If his expectations are not based in reality, realize this before you decide if it's worth taking the job.